# Detect email in text using regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I want to detect emails in text format so that I can put an anchor tag over them with mailto tag in anchor. I have the regex for it but the code also detects emails which are already encapsulated by anchor tag or is inside the anchor tag mailto parameter.

My regex is:

```
([\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)*@([a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*?\.[a-z]{2,6}|(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})(:\d{4})?)
```

But it detects 3 matches in the following sample text:

```
ttt <a href='mailto:someone@example.com'>someemail@mail.com</a> abc email@email.com
```

I want only email@email.com to be matched by the regex.

Comment: simply remove anchor tags before the regex execution...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903356/email-validation-regular-expression

Comment: be careful when [using regex to validate email](http://stackoverflow.com/q/201323/238902).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very similar to my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8833696/626273) to your other question, try this

```
(?<!(?:href=['"]mailto:|<a[^>]*>))(\b[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)*@([a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*?\.[a-z]{2,6}|(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})(:\d{4})?)
```

The only thing that is really different is the word boundary `\b` before the start of the email.

See a similar expression [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2vp6a), its not exactly the same, because Regexr does not support alternations and infinite length in the lookbehind.

Comment: One more question, your regex does not work when there is double quotes {"} in the anchor tag like: href="somelink" It works well for single quote in href in anchor tag. for example: href='somelink'  Can you help in editing the lookbehind so that is covers both single quote {'} and double quote {"}

Answer (score 2):

It's a better idea to leave the parsing of the HTML to something suitable for that (such as the [HtmlAgilityPack](http://nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack)) and combine that with regex to update the text nodes:

```
    string sContent = "ttt <a href='mailto:someone@example.com'>someemail@mail.com</a> abc email@email.com";
    string sRegex = @"([\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)*@([a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*?\.[a-z]{2,6}|(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})(:\d{4})?)";
    Regex Regx = new Regex(sRegex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);

    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(sContent);

    var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//text()[not(ancestor::a)]");
    foreach (var node in nodes)
    {
        node.InnerHtml = Regx.Replace(node.InnerHtml, @"<a href=""mailto:$0"">$0</a>");
    }
    string fixedContent = doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
```

I notice you've posted the same question [other forums as well](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/regexp/thread/83e25bf0-151d-4a20-9f86-88ad661705b2/), but haven't appointed an answer in any of them.