# Regex URL Replace, ignore Images and existing Links

Tags: c#, regex

I have a very good regex that works and is able to replace urls in a string to clickable once.

```
string regex = @"((www\.|(http|https|ftp|news|file)+\:\/\/)[_.a-z0-9-]+\.[a-z0-9\/_:@=.+?,##%&amp;~-]*[^.|\'|\# |!|\(|?|,| |>|<|;|\)])";
```

Now, how can I tell it to ignore already clickable links and images?

So it ignores below strings:

```
<a href="http://www.someaddress.com">Some Text</a>

<img src="http://www.someaddress.com/someimage.jpg" />
```

Example:

```
The website www.google.com, once again <a href="http://www.google.com">www.google.com</a>, the logo <img src="http://www.google.com/images/logo.gif" />
```

Result:

```
The website <a href="http://www.google.com">www.google.com</a>, once again <a href="http://www.google.com">www.google.com</a>, the logo <img src="http://www.google.com/images/logo.gif" />
```

Full HTML Parser code:

```
string regex = @"((www\.|(http|https|ftp|news|file)+\:\/\/)[_.a-z0-9-]+\.[a-z0-9\/_:@=.+?,##%&amp;~-]*[^.|\'|\# |!|\(|?|,| |>|<|;|\)])";
Regex r = new Regex(regex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

text = r.Replace(text, "<a href=\"$1\" title=\"Click to open in a new window or tab\" target=\"&#95;blank\" rel=\"nofollow\">$1</a>").Replace("href=\"www", "href=\"http://www");

return text;
```

Comment: good, hard to read, hard do maintain, easy with a HtmlParser..

Comment: Are you trying to parse HTML with a regular expression?

Comment: I answered this already [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8833696/626273)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex string issue in making plain text urls clickable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8833588/regex-string-issue-in-making-plain-text-urls-clickable)

Comment: Yes, I am trying to parse HTML, I just updated the Question and pasted all the code.

Comment: ... don't parse HTML with regex: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I'll post it the obligatory link if no one else will. [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

---

How about using a negative lookahead/behind for `"` like this:

`string regex = @"(?<!"")((www\.|(http|https|ftp|news|file)+\:\/\/)[_.a-z0-9-]+\.[a-z0-9\/_:@=.+?,##%&amp;~-]*[^.|\'|\# |!|\(|?|,| |>|<|;|\)])(?!"")";`

Comment: We should really stop providing workarounds after posting to the obligatory reference...

Comment: Agreed, but I wouldn't want to post an unhelpful comments as an answer either.

Comment: This worked for me: `(?<!\w?="")(((http|https|ftp|news|file)+://)[_.a-z0-9-]+\.[a-z0-9\/_:@=.+?,##%&amp;~-]*[^.|\'|\# |!|\(|?|,| |>|<|;|\)])`

Answer (score 1):

Check out: [Detect email in text using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8926301/detect-email-in-text-using-regex/8960753#8960753), just replace the regex for links, it will never replace a link inside a tag, only in contents.

http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Something like:

---

```
string textToBeLinkified = "... your text here ...";
const string regex = @"((www\.|(http|https|ftp|news|file)+\:\/\/)[_.a-z0-9-]+\.[a-z0-9\/_:@=.+?,##%&amp;~-]*[^.|\'|\# |!|\(|?|,| |>|<|;|\)])";
Regex urlExpression = new Regex(regex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);

HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(textToBeLinkified);

var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//text()[not(ancestor::a)]") ?? new HtmlNodeCollection();
foreach (var node in nodes)
{
    node.InnerHtml = urlExpression.Replace(node.InnerHtml, @"<a href=""$0"">$0</a>");
}
string linkifiedText = doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
```